# Firebase realtime database permission denied because of the rule

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

When I'm allowing "testName" read write true, it works at the child node however, when I'm allowing at the "test" and "testType" it makes permission denied even though I insert test and testType. How can I solve this problem?

```
"game": { 
      "$gamerid": {
        "$testName": {
            // ".read": true,
            // ".write": true,
            
            "test": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": true,
            },
            "testType": {
            ".read": true, 
            ".write": true,
            },
        }   
      }
    },
```

Comment: Can you share your query so we can check which node you are trying to accesss ?

Comment: Show us the code that you are using.

Comment: @Alex Mamo
database.child("users").child(userID).child("game").child(gamerid).child(testName).child("test").setValue("a" : "B")